# Why ReactNative TextInput is implemented this way?

Tags: android, react-native

if you have any experience with native `Android`, you know that each `EditText` saves its value in itself. i mean in react native you have to update `state` when user types anything but isn't this bad?

in android you can reach the Edittext and then call some methods like getText() or sth but in react native you have to read the value in state! it means more coupling! because you are using an state for a component which is in another Component for example.

for what reason react native is using this approach which seems old! in older C# you had sth like this approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, react support `Controlled` and `Uncontrolled` style. Controlled means having all value in sync with form's state. It seems complicated at first but will provide you flexibility in terms of validation and rendering.

Here are some documents you can reference:

- Controlled Component in reactjs doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html
- Using `ref` for `Uncontrolled component` in react native: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation
- A nice blog comparing controlled vs uncontrolled components https://goshakkk.name/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/